# sql join through link table merging duplicates comma separated

Tags: sql, join, sqlite

I have a classical Three-table-join:

- Book (BookID, Title, ...)
- Person (PersonID, Name, ...)
- PersonBookLink (BookID, PersonID, Role)

I have the classical `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT Book.Title as title, Person.Name as author 
FROM PersonBookLink 
   INNER JOIN Book
      ON PersonBookLink.BookID = Book.BookID
   INNER JOIN Person
      ON PersonBookLink.PersonID = Person.PersonID
;
```

This works as expected, but I may have multiple entries for the same `Book` because it may have more then one Author

I would like to merge such records having just one entry for each `Book` and a combined `author` field in the form `"Author1, Author2, ..."`. Is this possible directly with SQL?

I know I can programmatically merge the records in the result set, but that is rather messy and I would like to avoid, if possible.

I am currently using a SQLite3 database, if it matters.

Note: I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093714/1714490), but I don't need to count results, but to concatenate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query can resolve your issue

```
SELECT Book.Title as title, group_concat(Person.Name) as author 
FROM PersonBookLink 
INNER JOIN Book ON PersonBookLink.BookID = Book.BookID 
INNER JOIN Person ON PersonBookLink.PersonID = Person.PersonID 
GROUP BY Book.Title
```

group_concat takes an optional second argument (a string) to use as the concatenation separator if you don't want a single ',' character.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT b.Title, GROUP_CONCAT(p.Name, ', ') as authors
FROM PersonBookLink pbl INNER JOIN
     Book b
     ON pbl.BookID = b.BookID INNER JOIN
     Person p
     ON pbl.PersonID = p.PersonID
GROUP BY b.Title;
```

Note that I introduced table aliases into your query.  They make the query easier to write and to read.